# Atomic Fission & Nuclear Force

Tags: particle-physics, atomic-physics

If the [strong interaction force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_interaction) between the quarks that make up protons & neutrons get stronger with distance, and if the [gluons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon) enabling that force [split up if enough energy is applied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_confinement) to them, giving rise to new quark-antiquark pairs, how can atomic fission work? How can atomic nuclei be split up if new quark pairs are created when gluons snap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up two related phenomena which occur at different energy scales.

The quark-gluon description of the nuclear force is the most parsimonious description at very high energies. By "high energies," I mean hot enough that the quarks within a nucleon can start to get excited and enter different "orbitals" within the nucleon, which we observe experimentally as a baryon whose mass, charge, spin and other quantum numbers don't correspond to a proton or neutron. This is an analogy to electrons in their various states orbiting a nucleus, where at high temperatures excited states become available.

At *extremely* high temperatures, the bound states that we call nucleons and mesons lose their relevance entirely, and the quarks and gluons can form a plasma of free particles.

Stable nuclei like uranium (which is only unstable if you think that a billion years is brief) are at very *low* energy. The quark and gluon degrees of freedom are completely hidden inside of the nucleons. The most effective model for nuclei is an interaction via the "residual strong force," which is often described in terms of nucleons trading quark-antiquark pairs bound into "mesons," such as the pion.

In fact, a very effective model of fission considers the entire nucleus as a single droplet of "nuclear fluid," with all of the details about even the nucleons averaged away. The search term is "liquid drop model."

---

To address your further questions from a comment below:

> The force that binds protons and neutrons together inside a nucleus of an atom is the strong residual force

I would say instead "the residual strong force." It's still the strong force, but most of the excitement happens inside of the nucleon. Only a small residue of this internal interaction is accessible from the outside. You might compare to the Van Der Waals interaction between atoms, which is a short-distance electrostatic attraction between electrically neutral objects.

> exchanging pairs of q-aq, tied by pions

The pion, also known as the "pi meson," *is* one example of a quark-antiquark bound state. There are three pions, whose quark contents are

$$
\newcommand\ket[1]{\left|{#1}\right>}
\begin{align}
\pi^+ &= \ket{u\bar d}
&
\pi^0 &= \frac1{\sqrt 2}\left(
\ket{u\bar u} - \ket{d \bar d}
\right)
&
\pi^- &= \ket{d\bar u}
\end{align}
$$

(Here $u$ is an up quark, and $\bar d$ is a down antiquark.)
So if you think about a pion-emission process,

$$
\begin{align}
p &\to n\pi^+
\\
\ket{uud} &\to \ket{udd} + \ket{u\bar d}
\end{align}
$$

then, within the context of the quark model, you have the formation of a $d\bar d$ pair.  When a proton and neutron exchange a charged pion, the effect is that the proton and neutron swap places. Drawing the Feynman diagrams for this exchange is instructive; it's a great first effort at Feynman diagrams, if you haven't studied them yet.

There are lots of other mesons, with various quark contents and quantum numbers.

> from the quarks that stray too close from their origin proton/neutron to the neigbouring proton/neutron

This misunderstanding gets close to what I discussed in the first part of my answer.

There's a pop-science view in which a quantum-mechanical atom is a busy, whirling place whose more fundamental constituents are constantly doing lots of complicated things. The evidence for this busyness and whirlingness comes from interactions where you drive transitions in that atom. It's true. The inside of an atom is busy. Likewise, the inside of a proton is busy.

But at the same time, it is *also* true that the ground state of a quantum-mechanical system is generally a *stationary* state. If the quarks in a proton were whirling around and "sometimes" got "too close" to another particle, that would suggest that protons with distant quarks are somehow different from protons whose quarks are better-behaved.  But one of the fundamental lessons of quantum mechanics is that *all* protons are *exactly* the same: they are completely indistinguishable. It's this indistinguishability which gives us Pauli's exclusion principle, which doesn't apply to distinguishable particles.

The idea that a system's ground state is *both* dynamic *and* static is a little strange; it takes some practice with quantum mechanics to feel out quite what it means.

> what exactly do you mean "degrees of freedom"?

This is a closely related question.

Suppose that you are fixing a car that's not running right. You determine that the number three cylinder has a bad spark plug wire.  So you get in this car (which runs, just not as smoothly as you'd like) and drive down to the car parts store to get a replacement. While you're driving, the bad spark plug doesn't *really* affect the operation of the car.  You still make it go faster or slower by pushing the gas and brake pedals, and you change its direction by turning the steering wheel. The behavior of the spark plug is very interesting when you have your head in the engine, but it averages out and is less relevant if you are driving the car.

The traffic reporter watching from her helicopter, preparing her news update about which streets are congested and which streets are clear, doesn't care about your one bad spark plug wire *at all*.

Calling this a "degree of freedom" has a mathematical meaning which I'm not sure how to explain briefly.

Comment: So to make sure I'm understanding what you are saying;
The force that binds protons and neutrons together inside a nucleus of an atom is the strong residual force, which is the protons and neutrons exchanging pairs of q-aq, tied by pions, that result from the quarks that stray too close from their origin proton/neutron to the neigbouring proton/neutron, right? Does that exchange in itself become the "meson", or is the "meson" the result of that exchange? Also, what exactly do you mean "quark and gluon degrees of freedom"?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: @rob, I had a college friend who drove an ailing 1973 Ford galaxie LTD fastback hardtop with the 352 V-8 in which one exhaust valve was so badly burnt that it was essentially running on 7 cylinders. It ran a little rough but would still cross the Rockies, with a slight loss in fuel economy. SO... I like your analogy!

Comment: @rob thank you so much for this informative answer, it's helped me clear up the confusion regarding the strong force within atomic nuclei.
Regarding your answer about degrees of freedom, I understand what the mathematical definition of a degree of freedom is, my clarification regarding that was more related to exactly what a "quark and gluon" degree of freedom means, not the degree of freedom in general. I apologize for the confusion, I should have been more specific with my clarification.

Comment: @rob Your explanation of the pion exchange between protons and neutrons resulting in the two swapping places is very clear. The diagrams you showed illustrate that.
Another deeper question I had regarding your post, and maybe this clarification requires a new post, and if that's the case let me know, is how exactly does an exchange of a quark between a pair of protons/neutrons cause the pair to be drawn closer together? Is the pion physically acting as a "spring", pulling each other closer together? Or does the exchanged quark draw the quarks inside the protons/neutrons closer to each other?

Comment: You can't answer that question using just the quark model. There are other "isospin vector" mesons, such as the rho, who have the same quark *content* as the isovector pions but whose contribution to the nucleon-nucleon interaction is repulsive instead of attractive, because of other quantum numbers involved.